# Display bool value in datatable

Tags: javascript, asp.net, model-view-controller

I am trying to display boolean value in datatable. In my model I created field:

```
public bool Arb { get; set; }
```

In my View I created datatable which contain list of Medical Provider, and I want to add ARB field in every name, as you can see from picture

[image: Picture 1]

SO far I created this part

**View.cshtml**

```
<div class="col-md-6">         
    <table class="table datatable-responsive datatable-medical-map" id="medProviders" style="width:100%" @*title="Arbitration"*@>
    <thead>
            <tr class="bg-info">
                <th>Medical Provider (* Choose one)</th>
                <th>Distance (miles)</th>
                <th>Duration</th>                                                                                                     
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>                                                   
            @{  
                int i = 0;
                foreach (var item in medProviders)
                {
                    <tr class="sortList" style="cursor:pointer" id="increment-@i" data-id="@item.Id" data-lat="@item.Latitude" data-long="@item.Longitude">
                        <td>@item.Firstname</td>                                                                                   
                        <td id="distance-@i"></td>
                        <td id="duration-@i"></td>
                    </tr>
                    i++;
                }
            }
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <p id="medicalValidation"></p>
</div>
```

And I created JavaScript for appending when I click on Medical Provider

```
$(".town").click(function() {
    $.getJSON("/NfDocuments/LoadMedicalProviders", {
            town: $(this).attr('data-town')
        },
        function(data) {
            $('#medProviders').empty();
            var p = 0;
            $.each(data, function() {
                $("#medProviders").append("<tr class='sortList' style='cursor:pointer' id='increment-" + p + "' data-id='" + this.Id + "'  data-lat='" + this.Lat + "' data-long='" + this.Lon + "'><td>" + this.Title + "</td><td id='distance-" + p + "'><br/></td><td id='duration-" + p + "'></td></tr>");
                p++;
            });
        });
});
```

Add ViewBag to transfer data from Controller to View:

```
var medProviders = db.Contacts.Where(x => x.ContactCategory.Name == "Facility" && x.Firstname != null).ToList();
ViewData["medProviders"] = medProviders;
```

So to be clean, I only want to display ARB in Medical Provider list,and I want to put some icon instead of writing ARB

```
<i class="fa fa-heart" style="font-size:24px"></i>
```

I hope you understand what I need, if no please write in comment below I will try to describe one more time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this?

```
  if(item.Arb) {
    <i class="fa fa-heart" style="font-size:24px"></i>
  } else {
    // display something else, or nothing at all!
  }
```

Comment: You need
 if(item.Arb == true) {
<i class="fa fa-heart" style="font-size:24px"></i>
  } else {
    // display something else, or nothing at all!
  }
}